# How to check if a variable is alphanumeric if a certain condition has been met

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to check if the length of the user's username is 7. If the condition is satisfied, then I want to check if it is alphanumeric. If it isn't, I want to return the error below.

> You have entered an invalid username

***Here is My code***

```
def clean(self):
        super(Register, self).clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        
        if password.islower():
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password must contain an uppercase"])
        
        elif password.isnumeric():
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password must contain an alphabet"])

        elif password.isalpha():
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password must contain a number"])

        elif len(password) < 8:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password is too short"])

        elif password != password2:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["The two password fields must match"])

        elif len(username) !=7  and len(username) != 9:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["You have entered an invalid username"])

        else:
            pass
        
        try:
            if len(username) == 9:
                username = int(username)
        except ValueError:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["You have entered an invalid username"])

        if len(username) == 7:
            if username.isalnum() is False:
                self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Youuuu have entered an invalid username"])
            else:
                pass
        else:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["You have entered an invalid username"])

        for instance in User.objects.all():
            if instance.username == username:
                self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["User already exist"])
            elif instance.email == email:
                self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["E-mail already in use"])
            else:
                pass

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What is the question? You could shorten it like: `if not (len(username) == 7 and username.isalnum()):` `self.erros...`.

Comment: Is this code part of a class? Can you paste the whole thing and explain what the problem is?

Comment: @anarchy, my problem is that I want two different users to fill out the registration form and I want to be able to validate the users. It is a registration form for staff and students. Staff id is alphanumeric and its length is 7 while student id is totally numeric and length is 9. So my problem is that I am unable to validate  the staff id

Comment: regex would be better for this issue.

Comment: @Olasubomi can you also paste register? and how you are running the actual main code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no space to paste this in the comments so I'll try to answer the question first.

Your syntax for defining a class is wrong it should look something like this...

I am guessing the class is going to be called Clean and the Clean class is derived from the Register class?

```
class Clean(Register):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__().clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

    
        if password.islower():
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password must contain an uppercase"])
        
        elif password.isnumeric():
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password must contain an alphabet"])

        elif password.isalpha():
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password must contain a number"])

        elif len(password) < 8:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Password is too short"])

        elif password != password2:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["The two password fields must match"])

        elif len(username) !=7  and len(username) != 9:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["You have entered an invalid username"])

        else:
            pass
        
        try:
            if len(username) == 9:
                username = int(username)
        except ValueError:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["You have entered an invalid username"])

        if len(username) == 7:
            if username.isalnum() is False:
                self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["Youuuu have entered an invalid username"])
            else:
                pass
        else:
            self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["You have entered an invalid username"])

        for instance in User.objects.all():
            if instance.username == username:
                self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["User already exist"])
            elif instance.email == email:
                self.errors[''] = self.error_class(["E-mail already in use"])
            else:
                pass

        return self.cleaned_data
```

So figure out what exactly you are trying to instantiate first. And the we can try to help.

If you just want to see what the logic looks like for the question you asked. It should look like this. First you need to create a new variable in the class called "role" so you can store whether the person is a student or teacher. Then you can do this within the class.

```
if self.role == 'teacher':
    if len(self.id) == 7 and self.id.isalnum():
        print('success')
    else:
        print('whatever error code you want here')

elif self.role == 'student':
    if len(self.id) == 9 and self.id.isnumeric():
        print('success')
    else:
        print('whatever error code you want here')

else:

    print('error no role given')
```

This is just a starting point because the class you created up there is messy. But you should be able to use this to create what you want.

Comment: I wasn't declearing a class. `def clean(self)` is a method used in django forms.py for validating a form.